# Symfony2 ignores form validation of collection

Tags: php, validation, email, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a problem with Symfony2 and the validation of an email addresses collection.

**Entity\User**

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Email[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Email", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $emails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add emails
     *
     * @param Email $emails
     * @return User
     */
    public function addEmail(Email $emails)
    {
        if($emails->getEmail() !== null && strlen($emails->getEmail()) > 0)
        {
            $emails->setUser($this);
            $this->emails[] = $emails;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove emails
     *
     * @param Email $emails
     */
    public function removeEmail(Email $emails)
    {
        $emails->setUser();
        $this->emails->removeElement($emails);
    }

    /**
     * Set emails
     *
     * @param Email[] $emails
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmails($emails)
    {
        $this->emails = array();

        foreach($emails as $email)
        {
            $this->addEmail($email);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emails
     *
     * @return Email[]
     */
    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }
}
```

**Entity\Email**

```
/**
 * Email
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Email
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Email(checkMX = false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $user;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**UserType**

```
/**
 * Class UserType
 */
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new EmailType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

**EmailType**

```
/**
 * Class EmailType
 */
class EmailType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'email')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
}
```

The assert annotation is included in all entities.

The problem is that i can save the form without a valid email address.

- 123@example.org <- thats saved <- thats correct
- 123 <- thats saved <- thats **NOT** correct / no valid email address!
- `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO email (email, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null]` <- If i use "by_reference" = true i get this error and if "by_reference" is false i have no error...

I hope you could help me :)

Comment: Did you run 'php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force' command ?

Comment: Hmm now it works... But i dont know why >.<

Comment: if you get help from  my answer, then accept it and press up vote. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `'cascade_validation' => true,` in your default options?

Comment: Yes i had tried this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command from your terminal:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```